# Magento 2: How to disable Quantity Box for specific product from checkout cart and minicart

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, mini-cart

How can we disable Quantity Box for specific product from checkout cart and minicart?

I have already search for the solution but it will disable quantity for all products reference [URL](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/208042/62614)

Your help will be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your custom module, do following steps.

> Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {
            'Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/item/default.html': '[Vendor]_[Module]/template/minicart/item/default.html'
        }
    }
};
```

> Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<li class="item product product-item" data-role="product-item">
    <div class="product">
        <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
        <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url, title: product_name}" tabindex="-1" class="product-item-photo">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </a>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
        <span class="product-item-photo">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </span>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <div class="product-item-details">
            <strong class="product-item-name">
                <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
                <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, html: product_name"></a>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
                    <!-- ko text: product_name --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </strong>

            <!-- ko if: options.length -->
            <div class="product options" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "saveState": false}}'>
                <span data-role="title" class="toggle"><!-- ko i18n: 'See Details' --><!-- /ko --></span>

                <div data-role="content" class="content">
                    <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Options Details' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
                    <dl class="product options list">
                        <!-- ko foreach: { data: options, as: 'option' } -->
                        <dt class="label"><!-- ko text: option.label --><!-- /ko --></dt>
                        <dd class="values">
                            <!-- ko if: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                                <span data-bind="html: option.value.join('<br>')"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko ifnot: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                                <span data-bind="html: option.value"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </dd>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->

            <div class="product-item-pricing">
                <!-- ko if: canApplyMsrp -->

                <div class="details-map">
                    <span class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Price'"></span>
                    <span class="value" data-bind="i18n: 'See price before order confirmation.'"></span>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: canApplyMsrp -->
                <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('priceSidebar') -->
                    <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_price, as: 'price'} --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->

                <div class="details-qty qty">
                    <label class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Qty', attr: {
                           for: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty'}"></label>
                    <input data-bind="attr: {
                           id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           'data-item-qty': qty,
                           'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
                           }, value: qty, enable: isCustomizedEnabledQtyBox"
                           type="number"
                           size="4"
                           class="item-qty cart-item-qty">
                    <button data-bind="attr: {
                           id: 'update-cart-item-'+item_id,
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           title: $t('Update')
                           }"
                            class="update-cart-item"
                            style="display: none">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Update'"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="product actions">
                <!-- ko if: is_visible_in_site_visibility -->
                <div class="primary">
                    <a data-bind="attr: {href: configure_url, title: $t('Edit item')}" class="action edit">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <div class="secondary">
                    <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-cart-item': item_id, title: $t('Remove item')}"
                       class="action delete">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Remove'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

> Vendor/ModuleName/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem" />
</config>
```

> Vendor/ModuleName/Plugin/Magento/Checkout/CustomerData/DefaultItem.php

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\Magento\Checkout\CustomerData;

class DefaultItem extends \Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem
{
    protected function doGetItemData()
    {
        $result = parent::doGetItemData();
        $result['isCustomizedEnabledQtyBox'] = $this->isQtyBoxEnabled($this->item->getProduct()->getSku());
        return $result;
    }

    protected function isQtyBoxEnabled($sku)
    {
        $disabled = ['24-MB02'];
        if(!in_array($sku, $disabled))
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

After this,

```
 rm -rf generated/ var/view_preprocessed/ pub/static/frontend/ 
 php bin/magento setup:static-content-deploy -f 
 php bin/magento c:f
```

Clear all your browser cache and check. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

@yash Shah : thanks for your solution, it's great !
However, how to inject an helper in file

> Vendor/ModuleName/Plugin/Magento/Checkout/CustomerData/DefaultItem.php
> To get the sku list ?
> I tried to add it in __construct like usual injections but everytime my helper is null.
> Thanks

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\Magento\Checkout\CustomerData;

class DefaultItem extends \Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem
{
    protected $myHelper;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper,
        \Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data $msrpHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ConfigurationPool $configurationPool,
        \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data $checkoutHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper = null,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Configuration\Item\ItemResolverInterface $itemResolver = null,
        \[Vendor]\[Module]\Helper\Data $myHelper = null
) {
    $this->myHelper = $myHelper;
    parent::__construct($imageHelper, $msrpHelper, $urlBuilder, $configurationPool, $checkoutHelper, $escaper, $itemResolver);
}
    protected function doGetItemData()
    {
        $result = parent::doGetItemData();
        $result['isCustomizedEnabledQtyBox'] = $this->isQtyBoxEnabled($this->item->getProduct()->getSku());
        return $result;
    }

    protected function isQtyBoxEnabled($sku)
    {
        $disabled = explode([' , ',' ,',', ',','],$this->myHelper->getDisabledSkus());
        if(!in_array($sku, $disabled))
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

$this->myHelper is always null on line $disabled = ...