# Magento 2.3.0: How to disable Quantity Box for specific product from checkout cart and minicart

Tags: magento2

I want to disable the quantity box for specific custom products.

i followed [this tutorial](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/261710/magento-2-how-to-disable-quantity-box-for-specific-product-from-checkout-cart-a) but it did not work.

in my custom module, i did the following steps.

```
Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

var config = {
            'Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/item/default.html': '[Vendor]_[Module]/template/minicart/item/default.html'
        }
```

and then i :

> Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html

```
    <div class="product-item-details">
        <strong class="product-item-name">
            <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
            <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, html: product_name"></a>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
                <!-- ko text: product_name --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </strong>

        <!-- ko if: options.length -->
        <div class="product options" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "saveState": false}}'>
            <span data-role="title" class="toggle"><!-- ko i18n: 'See Details' --><!-- /ko --></span>

            <div data-role="content" class="content">
                <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Options Details' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
                <dl class="product options list">
                    <!-- ko foreach: { data: options, as: 'option' } -->
                    <dt class="label"><!-- ko text: option.label --><!-- /ko --></dt>
                    <dd class="values">
                        <!-- ko if: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                            <span data-bind="html: option.value.join('<br>')"></span>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                        <!-- ko ifnot: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                            <span data-bind="html: option.value"></span>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </dd>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </dl>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <div class="product-item-pricing">
            <!-- ko if: canApplyMsrp -->

            <div class="details-map">
                <span class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Price'"></span>
                <span class="value" data-bind="i18n: 'See price before order confirmation.'"></span>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko ifnot: canApplyMsrp -->
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('priceSidebar') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_price, as: 'price'} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->

            <div class="details-qty qty">
                <label class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Qty', attr: {
                       for: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty'}"></label>
                <input data-bind="attr: {
                       id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
                       'data-cart-item': item_id,
                       'data-item-qty': qty,
                       'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
                       }, value: qty, enable: isCustomizedEnabledQtyBox"
                       type="number"
                       size="4"
                       class="item-qty cart-item-qty">
                <button data-bind="attr: {
                       id: 'update-cart-item-'+item_id,
                       'data-cart-item': item_id,
                       title: $t('Update')
                       }"
                        class="update-cart-item"
                        style="display: none">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Update'"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="product actions">
            <!-- ko if: is_visible_in_site_visibility -->
            <div class="primary">
                <a data-bind="attr: {href: configure_url, title: $t('Edit item')}" class="action edit">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <div class="secondary">
                <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-cart-item': item_id, title: $t('Remove item')}"
                   class="action delete">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Remove'"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then my di

> Vendor/ModuleName/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem" />
</config>
```

> Vendor/ModuleName/Plugin/Magento/Checkout/CustomerData/DefaultItem.php

```
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\Magento\Checkout\CustomerData;

class DefaultItem extends \Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem
{
    protected function doGetItemData()
    {
        $result = parent::doGetItemData();
        $result['isCustomizedEnabledQtyBox'] = $this->isQtyBoxEnabled($this->item->getProduct()->getSku());
        return $result;
    }

    protected function isQtyBoxEnabled($sku)
    {
        $disabled = ['24-MB02'];
        if(!in_array($sku, $disabled))
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

**This is my disabled virables:**

```
 protected function isQtyBoxEnabled($sku)
    {
        $disabled = ['ChateauUndertheStars-1-DomeByLand-30','ChateauUndertheStars-1-DomeBySea-17'];
        if(!in_array($sku, $disabled))
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What is the error you got in console?

Comment: hi @Ranganathan. thanks for response. i am not getting any errors in the console

Answer (score 0):

Found an issue in this code, Please replace requirejs-config.js as below

```
var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {
            'Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/item/default.html': '[Vendor]_[Module]/template/minicart/item/default.html'
        }
    }
};
```

And Run below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content-deploy -f
```

This is worked in my Magento 2.3.2 env

Comment: hi. it did not work. no idea where i have gone wrong

Comment: What is your sku that you restricted?

Comment: hi. its     ChateauUndertheStars-1-DomeByLand-30

Comment: Did you added these skus in `$disabled` variable?

Comment: hi. yes i did. i have amended my original question to how the disabled variables

Comment: Check your mini cart, is that `default.html` overridden?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100673/discussion-between-theseeker-and-ranganathan).

Comment: how do i check if the mini cart is overridden? --can we contiues this in chat

Comment: Yes pls...I'm already in chat.

Comment: hi mate. would love to finish our discussion when you have time

Comment: Yes....can we start?

Comment: please come on chat

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100673/discussion-between-theseeker-and-ranganathan

Comment: Hey mate...Sorry i didn't get any notification in chat..Shall we continue our discussion ?